# Could not connect to local postgres DB from docker using pgadmin4

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pgadmin-4

I tried connecting to my local postgres DB from docker using pgadmin4 but it failed with `unable to connect to server: timeout expired`. I have my server running, and I used the same properties that are mentioned in the docker-compose.yml file while connecting to server in pgadmin4.

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
web:
    build:
        context: .
    ports:
        - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
        - ./app:/app
    command: >
        sh -c "python manage.py migrate &&
               python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    environment:
        - DB_HOST=db
        - DB_NAME=app
        - DB_USER=postgres
        - DB_PASS=secretpassword
    depends_on:
        - db

db:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=app
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secretpassword
```

This is the screenshot of the error I get in pgadmin4

[image]

I tried changing the host address to something like localhost, host.docker.internal, 127.0.0.1 and the IPAddress by inspecting docker container. But I get the same result every time. I also tried adding pgadmin4 as a service in my docker-compose.yml file and tried, but got the same result there too.

I am confused what I am missing here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you didn't export any port from Postgres Container which might be `5432` as default, then you can't connect `8000` because that is binding for your application from your host.

Here is some description from docker-compose [ports](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports)

> When mapping ports in the `HOST`:`CONTAINER` format, you may experience erroneous results when using a container port lower than 60, because YAML parses numbers in the format xx:yy as a base-60 value. For this reason, we recommend always explicitly specifying your port mappings as strings.

so you can try to export port `"5432:5432"` from Postgres DB from container which your Pgadmin might need to use 5432 port.

```
version: "3"

services:
web:
    build:
        context: .
    ports:
        - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
        - ./app:/app
    command: >
        sh -c "python manage.py migrate &&
               python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    environment:
        - DB_HOST=db
        - DB_NAME=app
        - DB_USER=postgres
        - DB_PASS=secretpassword
    depends_on:
        - db
db:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    ports:
        - "5432:5432"
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=app
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secretpassword
```

Comment: I was having the same issue, but in my case using the correct port 5432. Still getting the same error. Using `host.docker.internal` as host name / address did it.